# Get category of a taxonomy for a queries object in a loop

Tags: categories, terms

I am trying to get the category name of a custom post type category in my single-[cpt].php file.

Here is the code I am using:

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_name = $queried_object->name;
echo $term_name;
```

The category is a sub category. This code just displays the name of the parent category, where I need the name of the category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure in what form you need the term/s, but here's a piece of code that will first get all your posts' terms, then print them out as linked names.

```
<?php
// Get Post Terms
$taxonomy_slug = "your-taxonomy";
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );
if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {
  foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $out[] = '<a href="'. get_term_link( $term->slug, $taxonomy_slug ) .'">'. $term->name
. "</a>\n";
  }
  echo implode(', ', $out );
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you very very much 'The J'. This works Perfectly. I have been playing around with loops for hours with no success. Thanks again

Comment: You're welcome! Remember to tick it as the correct answer, if it's what you were looking for!